# OpenERP - tree view structure for form and tree view types

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using Odoo v8 (Ubuntu). 
The pictures below show "Bill of Material Structure" view when

```
<field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

and when

```
<field name="view_type">form</field>
```

in the following code in mrp module, mrp_view.xml:

```
<record id="action2" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Bill of Materials Structure</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">mrp.bom.line</field>
    <field name="domain">[('bom_id', 'in', active_ids)]</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="mrp_bom_tree_view"/> 
    <field name="view_type">tree</field> 
</record>
```

Is there a way to show indented tree structure for view_type = form, to look like when view_type = tree (with indentation)?

This is the tree view when view_type = tree:
[image]

This is the list view when view_type = form:

[image]

Here product 300-0005 is not expanded but it should be.
Note that using

```
<field name="field_parent">child_ids</field>
```

for the view with view type = form did not work.
Question that can be asked is how to display hierarchical tree view as indented list view?

Comment: You cant, you need to use the tree type view to expand

Comment: @DanielCrocco Do you have any idea how I can export the tree type view to Excel?

Comment: Not really sorry that i can't help you with that, why you need it in Excel exactly? maybe we can find another way that isnt making a custom module exactly for that

Comment: @DanielCrocco  The users want it in Excel, it's convenient for them. Another option is to print or export to PDF.

Comment: Well with a normal print to pdf (Ctrl + P) you can see that view in pdf :)

Comment: @DanielCrocco That's true and I suggested and showed that to users. It looks like they still want a button in the header of the tree view page.